# Tracking Rotating Sprite

Tags: c#, xna

I am messing about in XNA and have run into  a problem. I have a 48 * 48 sprite that I can keep track of its location in the game world by the top left corner of the sprite.
I want to be able to rotate the square and still keep track of the same point. For instance if I rotate 90degrees clockwise and the orginal X position was 200 the new X position should be 200 + 48(the size of the width of the image). Its fine for 90 degrees I am able to work that out in my head but each one in between is the problem!
I know there is probably some kind of formula to work this out.
Any help would be great! Oh the square is rotating on its center.

I'm just using `spriteBatch.Draw()`

```cs
      spriteBatch.Draw( animations[currentAnimation].Texture,
            Camera.WorldToScreen(WorldRectangle),
            animations[currentAnimation].FrameRectangle,
            color, rotationScale , new Vector2((float)frameHeight/2, (float)frameWidth/2), effect, TileMap.characterDepth);
```

Comment: show us code where you draw that sprite

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep track of a moving rotating sprite you can't use the top left corner, but its centroid. You already draw your sprite using the centroid to rotate it.

The problem is that the second parameter of your `Draw` call is a `Rectangle`, you sholud use a `Vector2` position, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're building your application on top of a 3D graphics library.  3D graphics libraries are very good at solving this kind of problem!  Break it down into smaller operations and let the library do the work for you.

First:  it's easiest to think about these kinds of questions when you're working in *model space* rather than *world space*.  In other words:  you don't need to worry about where the rotating point is in absolute terms, you only need to worry about where it is relative to the untransformed model (in this case, your sprite without any rotation or translation).

So where is that?  Simple:

```
var pt = new Vector3(-frameWidth / 2f, -frameHeight / 2f, 0f);
```

Your point of origin is the center of your sprite, so the center of your sprite in model space is (0, 0).  This means that the top left corner of your sprite is half the width of the sprite in the negative x direction, and half the height of the sprite along the negative y direction.

Now create an object that represents the desired transformation.  You can do this by creating a rotation matrix using XNA's built-in methods:

```
var transformation = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(90f));
```

Now apply the transformation to your original point:

```
var transformedPt = Vector3.Transform(pt, transformation);
```

This is still in model space, remember, so to get world coordinates you'll need to transform it into world space:

```
var transformedWorldX = transformedPt.X + spritePosition.X;
var transformedWorldY = transformedPt.Y + spritePosition.Y;
```

And there you go.